# cannot access my website to other computer using domain name but can access using ip address

Tags: php, html, dns, wamp

I can access my website in my computer using my ip address 192.168.X.X.

I can access my website in my computer using  domain name
 www.dcnational1.com

=======================================================================

I can access my website in other computer using my ip address 192.168.X.X

i can't access my website in other computer using domain name

My question is how to access my website in other computer using both ip address and domain name.

I am using wamp server 3.1.3

## This is my httpd-vhosts.conf code

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName dcnational1.com
  ServerAlias www.dcnational1.com
  DocumentRoot "D:\wamp\www\Ritehly"
  <Directory "D:\wamp\www\Ritehly">
   Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted


  </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
```

================================================================

## And This is my httpd.conf important code.

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80

ServerName localhost:80

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "D:\wamp\www\Ritehly"
<Directory "D:\wamp\www\Ritehly">

AllowOverride all



    Require all granted



<Files ".ht*">
    Require all granted
</Files>
```

## Virtual hosts

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

## my Host

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   dcnational1.com
127.0.0.1   www.dcnational1.com

127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1 localhost
0.0.0.0 local
```

[My wamp server 3.1.3 is already in ONLINE MODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYEUk.png)

Comment: `192.168.*.*` is part of the private network block, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network Your “other computer” must be in the same LAN or something for that to work in the first place.

Comment: @misorude sorry for that man i mean ALL CAPS is to highlight everything.I already edited it man. thanks

Comment: @misorude I am in my office sir misorude, i don`t know if it is block or not,

Comment: unless you have a dns server on your LAN then other computers will not know that a certain IP belongs to a certain name - other computers on the LAN therefore must employ some method of ip/name translation - with windows you can edit the `hosts` file

Comment: If this is just local dev stuff, you should be able to just edit the *hosts* file on your second machine to point to the IP address of the first machine.

Comment: @RamRaider you mean sir that in order to access my website to other computer using domain name , i will not put dns server in my network panel? what do mean sir "employ some method of ip/name translation with with windows using host file. Can you give example in host file.

Comment: @CD001 thanks sir for answers, but i cannot access the host file of all the computer in my workplace sir 1 by 1 just to edit the host file.

Comment: other computers on your LAN need to know that `www.dcnational1.com` actually points to ip `192.168.X.X` - either edit the hots file of other computers or get your systems administrator to edit the DNS records for your network. I don't know what the "DNS server in my network panel" means - presumably that is something to do with WAMP. If you are in your office - do you have Active Directory?

Comment: @RamRaider changing the host to other computers has no chance, I can only edit mine other`s cannot. I can also change my DNS SERVER anytime but others computer cannot. Yes we in Active Directory here in the office.

Comment: your sys admin would need to add a ( A-Name) record to DNS so that other computers will identify that particular ip to that particular name. The DNS control of which you speak in WAMP will not have any bearing on other network clients on your LAN segment. It is unusual for Active Directory to be configured with a 192.168.x.x subnet however... and more unusual is running a webserver on a pc in a corporate environment rather than on a dedicated server or virtual server

Answer (score 0):

Your host file is wrong.
Point your domains not to 127.0.0.1 but to the real IP addresses (e.g. 192.168.1.1) and add that host file to all computers in your network.
You could also run your own DNS server in your network.

Comment: sir changing HOST file to other computer here has no chance sir I can only change or add something on host alone.

Answer (score 0):

Okay if there is no chance to access my website using DOMAIN NAME, I will instead publish my website so that any one who has access to internet can view my website.

Thank you guys, for the answers and comments.

Cheers, everyone newbie here and trying everything to learn more.

thanks,

And good day!